# SQL Transaction + Try-catch or VB.NET Transaction + Try-catch?

Tags: sql, vb.net, transactions

I'm working with an application which connects to a database. I definitely want to do a rollback if some database operations failed. I'm just wondering if which transaction + try-catch is better to use, the SQL or the VB.NET?

In VB.NET we can do something like:

```
Try

...

Catch ex As Exception
    MyTransaction.Rollback
End Try
```

If try catch is in SQL:

```
...
MyCommand.CommandText = _
"USE AdventureWorks2008R2; " & _
"GO " & _
"BEGIN TRANSACTION; " & _
"BEGIN TRY " & _
"    ... " & _
"END TRY " & _
"BEGIN CATCH " & _
"    SELECT  " & _
"        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber " & _
"        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity " & _
"        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState " & _
"        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure " & _
"        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine " & _
"        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; " & _
"    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 " & _
"        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; " & _
"END CATCH; " & _
"IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 " & _
"    COMMIT TRANSACTION; " & _
"GO " & _
MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I always use the first one, thru VB.NET. Is there any difference? What are those? Any drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the differences is the errors that are trapped.

- The SQL catch will catch errors that occur in the SQL query
- The VB.Net catch will catch errors that occur in VB.Net.  This includes both programming and many query errors which propagate through .Net APIs

Which you want to use is highly dependent upon your situation.  If all the VB.Net try block does is execute the query and roll back on errors then you're much better served doing the rollback in SQL.  This keeps the database logic tight and local.

However if the VB.Net try block includes say additional business logic then it probably makes more sense to keep the rollback there.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, they are they same - the vb.net version gets translated and run as  sql queries.

The main difference is that you can execute several SQL statements using the same connection without having to generate one large SQL query that contains everything you want done in the transaction.

Comment: _the vb.net version gets translated and run as sql queries_ -- The transaction, yes; the `try`…`catch`, no. This would only be possible in the first place if it was part of a LINQ query or part of an `Expression`.